# QML SwipeView two-finger swipe

Tags: qml

I'm using SwipeView and I want to prevent it from swiping from page to page with 1-finger swipes on a touchscreen. How to restrict SwipeView swiping to 2-finger swipes only?

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabs")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1Form {
        }

        Page2Form {
        }
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex

        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 1")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 2")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What a problem with this code?

Comment: @folibis There is no problem, I just want this to happen with 2 fingers

Comment: It is absolutely unclear from your question what works _incorrectly_.

Comment: I want, Do not swipe with one finger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Page1Form {
         MultiPointTouchArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                mouseEnabled: false
                minimumTouchPoints: 1
                maximumTouchPoints: 10
                onTouchUpdated:{
                    var pointId=[];
                    for (var touch in touchPoints){
                        pointId.push(touchPoints[touch].pointId);
                        //console.log(pointId);
                        if(pointId.length === 2){
                            swipeView.interactive = true;
                        }else{
                            swipeView.interactive = false;
                        }
                   }
               }
         }
  }
```